# module 'cryptography.utils' has no attribute 'register_interface'

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a python script that works when I run it manually from Visual Code. It errors when I run it from Azure portal.
`module 'cryptography.utils' has no attribute 'register_interface'`

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling PGPy but I'm still getting the same error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/998750/azure-databricks-attributeerror-pgpy

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import pgpy
import cryptography
from datetime import datetime

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
     logging.info('test1')
     try:
          now = datetime.now()
          date_time = now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
     except Exception as e:
          print(e)
          logging.error(e)
     finally:
          return func.HttpResponse(f"test")
```

Comment: Provide your script giving this error.